# Наборы символов (character sets) в стандарте C++

Tags: c++, кодировка, символы, стандарт, c++-faq

Часто встречаю понятия типа *basic character set*, *execution character set* и т.п.. Какие бывают наборы символов и чем они отличаются? Где какой применяется и зачем требуется их разграничение?

Comment: Не "символьные множества", а "наборы символов" или чаще "кодировки"

Comment: ну вот точно не кодировки

Answer (score 3):

С *basic character set* все просто - в документе n3337 в пункте 2.3 они описаны так

> The basic source character set consists of 96 characters: the space character, the control characters representing
> horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and new-line, plus the following 91 graphical characters

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
_ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & |  ! = , \ " ’
```

там есть поправка на их внешний вид, но это уже отдельно.

Там же рядом описана и *execution character set*

> The basic execution character set and the basic execution wide-character set shall each contain all the members of the basic source character set, plus control characters representing alert, backspace, and carriage return, plus a null character (respectively, null wide character), whose representation has all zero bits. For each basic execution character set, the values of the members shall be non-negative and distinct from one another.

то есть *basic character set* плюс ещё чуточку.

- ontrol characters representing alert - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character
- backspace
- carriage return
- a null character

думаю, что если немного закрыть глаза, то очень грубо можно сказать что это первые 128 символов таблицы аски (в прочем, как почти любой современной кодировки - cp1251, uft-8)